# Can't execute "mvn clean package" task in GO CD

Tags: maven, go-cd

I have setup a "Hello World" pipeline with one task `mvn clean package` in Go CD. I have registered an agent with Java and Maven up and running.

When I trigger the pipeline, the job fails:

```
12:05:08.655 [go] Start to execute task: <exec command="mvn" > <arg>clean package</arg> </exec>.
12:05:08.660 Error happened while attempting to execute 'mvn clean package'.  Please make sure [mvn] can be executed on this agent.
```

If I execute `mvn clean package` in my agent, everything works. What is happening? Is there a place where I can see more specific logs?

Comment: Looks like maven is not installed on that agent..

Comment: Yes, it looks like that. But it is installed, it is in the PATH, M2_HOME is defined and JAVA_HOME, too. I have only that agent, I can see it in "Agents" in the dashboard.

Comment: M2_HOME should not be defined. Only in the PATH for Maven...

Comment: It doesn't work anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running the following:

**Command**:

```
mvn clean package
```

try to use

**Command**:

```
/bin/bash
```

**Arguments**:

```
-c
mvn clean package
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue and figured out a solution which worked for me. Maybe, it will help you.

1. In the command prompt of your agent enter `echo $PATH`
2. This will show all your path variables. Copy all of them.
3. Now, in the GUI of your server, choose the configuration of your
   pipeline and add a PATH variable with the copied variables.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:
**Command**:

```
mvn
```

**Arguments**:

```
clean
package
```