# Error happened while attempting to execute 'mvn clean package' in Go CD

Tags: maven, go-cd

I have setup a pipeline with one task mvn clean package in Go CD. I have registered an agent with Java and Maven up and running. When I trigger the pipeline, the job fails:

[go] Task: mvn clean package took: 0.14s
Error happened while attempting to execute 'mvn clean package'.
Please make sure [mvn] can be executed on this agent.

[Debug Information] Environment variable PATH: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk/bin

I have tried all solutions provided on the below post-but nothing works
[Can't execute "mvn clean package" task in GO CD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37113514/cant-execute-mvn-clean-package-task-in-go-cd/66195720#66195720)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem，
If i execute
docker exec -it gocd-agent bash
and execute mvn --version,will not tip me error
but if i execute
docker exec -it gocd-agent sh,will tip me "mvn: command not found"
so i feel the problem is bash and sh 'difference.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

Run `whereis mvn` on your agent then copy the path where mvn is installed and use it as the command in GoCD.

For me it was like this:

**Command**

```
/opt/apache-maven-3.8.2/bin/mvn
```

**Arguments**

```
clean
package
```